# What's the reason for shapes not being compatible and how can I fix this?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

Context I actually did not code before but now I'm hoping to build a facial recognition system from fer2013. I encountered a problem when it came to building my CNN which is that the shapes of the labels (None, 7) and the image (23, 23, 7) are not compatible. I don't know where I went wrong. Below are the codes.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/fer2013.csv')

from csv import reader
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixels = df['pixels'].tolist() #1
faces = []
for pixel_sequence in pixels: #this lists down each row
  face = [int(pixel) for pixel in pixel_sequence.split()] #this lists down each integer as separate
  face = np.asarray(face).reshape(48,48)
  face = cv2.resize(face.astype('uint8'), (48,48)) 
  faces.append(face.astype('float32')) #### <-- this line
  face = face / 255.0
faces = np.asarray(faces)
faces = np.expand_dims(faces, -1)
emotions = np.array(pd.get_dummies(df['emotion']))

import sklearn.model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(faces,emotions, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics='accuracy')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size=300)
```

Comment: Before `Dense` layer, add a `Flatten()` layer.

Comment: @Frightera thanks! this actually worked. Although, now I'm facing a different problem which is that validation accuracy just plateaus at 40%

Comment: That is something about the model, also do not use dropouts unless you conclude that you are overfitting.

Comment: @Frightera yup, that helped actually. What's the reason behind not using dropouts early on? Is it because you might end up severing hidden neurons resulting in underfitting?

Comment: Exactly, dropout with a rate 0.5 means, you are *dropping* half of the units then.